# Using Eclipse to write Android apps using C#

Tags: c#, android, eclipse

Can we use Eclipse IDE to write Android apps using C#.

I tried everything to use `xamarin` for Android apps using c# in VS-2010 pro sp1

I installed

1) JDK 1.8 (both x-86 and 64)

2) set up JAVA_HOME (pointing to x-86)

3) Android SDK

4) Mono-Android

tried everything but failed googled for days asked for help here (SO)
but no luck

now I want to know is there a way I can use Eclipse IDE
(which is working fine on my machine for Android development using Java)
and C#.

Comment: Are you using VS 2010 Professional or higher? This seems to be the requirement to run xamarin on VS.

Comment: @Widi thanks man for reply i am using VS 2010 pro sp1

Comment: What exactly is not working? The installation or xamarin itself?

Comment: @Widi  Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK.  (Download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.)

Comment: Make sure you have the JAVA_HOME and the JAVA variable setup. Restart your PC and try again. If its still not working try reinstalling xamarin (full delete and the installing again).

Comment: @Widi where should JAVA variable point to ?

Comment: To the <jdk path>/bin folder

Comment: @Widi both variables set and restarted but nothing getting same error during build

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78624/discussion-between-widi-and-constantine).